# How to use the same theme that you bought?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-thesis-theme

I bought a theme from tavern and want to use the same theme pictures and everything. But when I install the theme I don't see the same pictures.

The theme that I bought looks like this:

[image: tavern theme screenshot]

This is how it looks like when I install it:

[image: tavern theme implementation gone wrong]

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all read the portfolio about the theme ... and it's very easy to import all you dummy data in you theme check your theme folder, It must be contain dummy data in xml format. Go in wp-admin dashboard click on tool-> click on import-> now chose wordpress import-> run and install wordpress importer . Now chose your xml file ...> Done

Answer (score 0):

When I quickly did a Google search, I found that [Travern](http://themeforest.net/item/tavern-professional-restaurant-theme/10984149) WordPress theme is from Theme Forest.

The [Travern theme](http://themeforest.net/item/tavern-professional-restaurant-theme/10984149) only includes PHP Files, HTML Files, CSS Files and JS Files during purchase and not the image files. If you're still unsure, you can check out the theme's [support](http://themeforest.net/item/tavern-professional-restaurant-theme/10984149/support) page and contact the theme author on your query. This should you help you resolve your query.